# Text position inline of a div

Tags: css, text, position

This is live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/5/

Everything is fine with that, until the text width there is higher than the div width.

If you will add some text there, the line will break and the text will be displayed under of the image instead of next to the image (as you can see in my first fiddle).

Here you can see what happends, it text width is higher than div container width:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/12/

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: What should it look like when it's fixed? This is your third question in a row on the same thing. This should only take one question. Make a few preview images of what it should look like with one, two, three lines of text. That, along with the code you've provided so far will get you results.

Comment: @thirtydot removing awkward comments is just pathetic... congratulations on your power abusing.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. I haven't removed any comments. From your attitude, I can certainly see why your comments would have been removed by a moderator (*hint: I'm not a moderator*).

Comment: @thirtydot Alright... I'm ok with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your right side content a width and float it to the right, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/14/

For a cleaner result, i suggest you separate both sides of your content, left and right, with a class and width and then float them to set them side by side.

Comment: Good point. But look, I've changed an image and it looks completly different... http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/17/ why does it happends?

Comment: @Cyclone the height of the image changed, and also the `margin-top:-7px` declaration is gone, that is why the container changed. You can define a width/height for the image to make sure that does not happen.

Comment: Well, I dont really want to change the image dimensions... wont this be possible without that?

Comment: @Cyclone Sure, just remove the whitespace that is found on the image, if you open it on an editor you can see that there is a large gap stemming from the top and bottom of the graphic itself. Or, adjust the whitespace using negative margins, though that is not suggested as the image will just adjust itself negatively. Though it works, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/18/ ..

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `display:inline-block;` from the CSS for the `span` element ([jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/13/)).

More information on [`display:inline-block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop).

> `inline-block`: This value causes an element to generate an inline-level block container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `display:inline-block` for the span. Remove it, and the text will be on the same line

Comment: Doesn't fix it (at least not in Chrome).

Comment: @skimberk1, I tested it in both Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/15/